# KDevelop crashed (closed unexpectedly)

Tags: crash, dbus, ide, kdevelop

I am try to run application "KDevelop" but return with the following error:

```
root@11:~$ kdevelop

 Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
    QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
    QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
    kbuildsycoca4 running...
    kbuildsycoca4(8881) KBuildSycoca::checkTimestamps: checking file timestamps
    kbuildsycoca4(8881) KBuildSycoca::checkTimestamps: timestamps check ok
    kbuildsycoca4(8881) kdemain: Emitting notifyDatabaseChanged ()
    kdevelop(8847)/kdevplatform (language): failed to open a repository 
    KCrash: Application 'kdevelop' crashing...
    KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
    KCrash: Connect sock_file=/home/user/.kde/socket-ws4/kdeinit4__1

    [1]+  Stopped                 kdevelop
```

I also remove and reinstall KDevelop but return same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get remove kdevelop` and `sudo apt-get purge kdevelop` completely. then try `locate kdevelop` and remove all files and directories in the list as: `sudo rm -rf /dir_path`.
reboot the system and reinstall application.